# Unable to achieve position sticky

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sticky

Here is a div; I want to make the image in the other column(6) sticky when it gets in view so I can update it while scrolling. But it has refused to work. Every other positioning method works apart from sticky

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-x">
                <div class="iphone">
                    <div>
                        <div class="section-header">
                            <div class="opportunity-image">
                            <img style="height: 30%; width: 50%" src="/images/advertise.svg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="section-title wow fadeInDown pt-4" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Create Opportunities</h2>
                        <!-- <div class="shape wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.3s"></div> -->

                        <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">Do you have Items or Products you want to sell? Or do you want to view and buy products? <br> You can view and also create opportunities from the comfort of your home and process all transactions and logistics right from there. Just wait at home and the goods come to you!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="iphone">
                     <div class="section-header">
                      <div class="opportunity-image">
                        <img  style="height: 30%; width: 50%"  src="/images/request.svg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="section-title wow fadeInDown p-4" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Make Requests</h2>
                        <!-- <div class="shape wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.3s"></div> -->
                        <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">Manage all your requests from your App and enjoy smooth operation on all orders</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="iphone">
                     <div class="section-header">
                     <div class="opportunity-image " >
                    <img  style="height: 30%; width: 50%"  src="/images/creditcard.svg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h2 class="section-title wow fadeInDown pt-4" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Make Payments</h2>
                    <!-- <div class="shape wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.3s"></div> -->
                    <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">Make Payments via our crypto method pegged to the naira. Once payments is made, Your coin is held in escrow until orders has been fulfilled! Secure payment guaranteed.Our Escrow system is safe and security guranteed. You can also withdraw or convert your coins to naira whenever you want</p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="iphone">
                <div class="section-header">
                <div class="opportunity-image " >
                        <img  style="height: 30%; width: 50%"  src="/images/creditcard.svg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h2 class="section-title wow fadeInDown pt-4" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Withdraw and Pay with Cryptocurrency pegged to the naira</h2>

                    <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">Do you have a product to sell?, Post it as an opportunity on our platform and let users send requests to buy them!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                 <!-- <div class="opportunity-image m float-right fixed"> -->
                    <img class="iphone-pic fixed float-right"  src="/images/spottr-image.png" alt="" >
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: did you add `top:0` when making the position:sticky?

Comment: added top of 10px because i don't want it to stick absolutely to the top

Comment: so it worked? ...

Comment: no it didn't work at all